# Prove $-(-a)=a$ using only ordered field axioms

Tags: analysis, field-theory, proof-explanation

I need to prove for all real numbers $a$, $-(-a) = a$ using only the following properties:

[image]
[image]

I tried by starting with P12 written using symbolic logic:

$\begin{align}
\forall a,b \in P \to & a \cdot b \in P \Leftrightarrow True \\
\forall a \in P \land \forall b \in P \to & a \cdot b \in P \Leftrightarrow True \\
\lnot \left[ \left( \forall a \in P \right) \land \left( \forall b \in P \right) \right] \lor & a \cdot b \in P \Leftrightarrow True \\
\exists a \notin P \lor \exists b \notin P \lor & a \cdot b \in P \Leftrightarrow True \\
\end{align} \\
$

and played with evaluating it with $b = -1$, $-a$ and so on. But, felt this wasn't really a solution because the last symbolic logic statement above is ambiguous.

Not to mention--other than P12--I haven't used any of the axioms listed above whatsoever. ( And I've not bothered to prove any of the theorems of symbolic logic I have used. )

Can anyone give me a start on this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Thank you, everyone! [I wrote up the proof I came up with using all of your help here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1904039/170148).

Best regards!

Comment: Consider the additive inverse of $-(-a)$ and what their sum is equal to. (hint additive inverses are unique)

Comment: Bear in mind -(-a) must equal something.  -a + a =0.  And -a + -(-a) =0 as well.  What does that tell you?

Comment: So from the answers you see that $-(-a) = a$ is valid for all fields.

Comment: and you can show$ -(-a)=a$ is already valid for groups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to prove that additive inverses are *unique*: That is, if there is a $b$ such that $a+b=0$ and a $c$ such that $a+c=0$, then $b=c$ (this is really why it makes sense to give the inverse a name, like $-a$). After you have done this, think about what the equation
$$-a+a=0$$
says about the additive inverse of $-a$.

Comment: Nitpick: you don't *have* to prove additive inverses are unique.  Let c be *one* of the inverses of one of of the inverses b of a.  Then a+b = 0 = c + b.  So a+b+a = c+b+a.  So a=c. Inadvertently proving the inverses of inverses are unique, before proving the inverses are unique.  But you *should* prove inverses are unique first.

Answer (score 1):

Try to prove the following statements:

$$0\cdot  a=0\text{ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$}$$

$$(-1)\cdot a=-a\text{ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$}$$

$$\text{The additive inverse is unique.}$$

Now prove $$(-a)+(-(-a))=0\text{ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$.}$$

Comment: Don't have to prove the last statement.  It's true by definition.  The first two statements are not nescessary yet.  (And will be easier to proof using a=-(-a))

Comment: Actually you have to show $$-(-a))=(-1)((-1)a)=((-1)(-1))a=1a=a$$

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to prove (and the proof is relatively standard) that:

$$ 0 \cdot a=0   $$

Then you can finish it off by substitution on both sides

$$[1+(-1)]\cdot a=a+(-a)$$
$$1a+(-1)a=a+(-a)$$
$$a+(-1)a=a+(-a)$$
Which will get the required result: 
$$(-1)a=(-a)$$

I'll leave you to observe what axioms I used. 
You may also wish to explore the fact that if $$a+b=a+c$$ 
then 
$$b=c$$

Or similarly; if $$a=b$$
then $$a+c=b+c$$
(When I studied this in linear algebra, I was told that this is a well assumed result and doesn't require justification) So you can also add the additive inverse to both sides in the above solution provided that you are allowed to assume this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the additive inverse of $a$ is $-a$, $P3$ implies that additive inverse of $-a$ is $a$, but we denote it by $-(-a)$; so $a=-(-a)$ (prove that additive inverse is unique.)

Answer (score 0):

It's barely a proof.  It's almost a definition.

$-a + a = 0;a+(-a)=0$

So $a $ is an additive inverse of $-a $.

For an additive inverse of $-a $ we call it $-(-a) $.

And that's it.

BUT there is one subtlety that everyone else has mentioned.  The proposition seems to assume (at least in its language) that there is only one unique additive inverse. (Was this one of the axioms?)  If this isn't so we can't really say that $-a $ is one specific number. It might represent many possible numbers.  I.E.  if $a + b =b+a =0$ and $a+c = c+a=0$ and $c\ne b $ then $-a $ can represent *either* $b $ or $c $.

If so $a $ is *one* of the values of $-(-a) $.  There might be others.  We have to show this can't happen by showing $a+b=b+a=0$ and $a+c=c+a=0$ and $b\ne c $ is impossible.

Then we will know $-a $ can only have one value and $-(-a) = a $; the one and only inverse of the one and only inverse of $a $ is $a $.

If $a+c=0;c+a=0$ and $a+b=0;b+a=0$ then $a+b=a+c $ .  So $b+a+b=b+a+c $ so $0+b=0+c $ and $b=c $.

So additive inverses are unique.  $-a $ represents one specific number only.  And $-(-a)=a $ and only $a $ (as, $-a +a=a+(-a)=0$).

Answer (score 0):

by Munna shigri

(-1)a=-a

proof:

LHS

(-1)a=(-1)a+0.   {a+0=a}

```
   =(-1)a+{a+(-a)}.     {a+(-a)=0}

   ={(-1)a+a}+(-a).    {by associative property}

   =a{(-1)+1} +(-a).   {by distributive property}

   =a{1+(-1)}+(-a).     {by commutative property }

    =a0 +(-a).               {a+(-a)=0}

    =0+(-a).                   {a0=0}

     = (-a)+0.                 {by commutative property}

      =-a. proved.            {a+0=a}
```