# Must $0 = -a + -(-a)$ be proven?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Given that for each a there is an element $$-a \in R$$ with the property that $$a + (-a) = 0$$ can I substitute a with $-a$ without a proof and conclude that $$0 = -a + - (-a)$$

Comment: Yes, because "for each" allows substitution.

Comment: Technically, you can say everything needs a proof. It is whether you consider something trivial enough to not write a proof.

Comment: A similar question is asked in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904003/prove-a-a-using-only-ordered-field-axioms) post.